# How to call on.exit() from parent?

Tags: r

Quite a few of my functions accept `file` argument (which defaults to `NULL`) which sets the graphics output file. E.g., `foo()` will plot to the screen, and `foo(file="bar.png")` will write the plot to file `"bar.png"`.

They have this code snippet in them:

```
  if (!is.null(file)) {
    cat("*** writing",file,"\n")
    do.call(tools::file_ext(file),list(file = file)) # set the device
    on.exit(dev.off())
  }
```

I wish I could create a function which would replace these 5 lines, but, alas, I cannot because `on.exit` would reset the graphics device too early.

What do people do in such a situation?

Comment: Why are you using `do.call`? What has `dev.off()` got to do with opening a file? You'd also be better off using `message()` instead of `cat()`

Comment: @hadley: I edited the question; does this answer your questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of repetition is best dealt with by creating a function that takes a code block and evaluates it in a [special context](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Special-environments#evaluate-code-in-a-special-context).  For example, you could write:

```
capture_png <- function(file, code) {
  if (!is.null(file)) {
    message("writing ", file)
    png(file)
    on.exit(dev.off())
  }
  code
}

capture_png(NULL, plot(1:10))
capture_png("test.png", plot(1:10))
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be because it will be forced automatically because it's the return value.

Comment: it is also the return value in `in_dir` on your page